# Framer-Motion: Animate text color change from left ro right

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I want an animation where the color of my text gets animated from left to right, but without staying in the new color.

For example:
Given a text "Text" with black color, the animation should start with making "T" red and then moves forward through the rest of text. Once the color of "e" is getting animated, color of "T" should move back to black.

Is this somehow possible with framer motion?

The only thing I can currently animate is changing the whole text color with Keyframes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-mirzakhani-mu3pm?file=/src/App.js:252-259

Comment: You could try using text gradient instead. Changing the percentage stops and similar via framer.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky is there maybe an example somewhere? I currently don't get your idea.

Comment: I'd start with first reading up on animating text gradient with CSS (including questions on SO). Then you can create the framer animation spring/effect to animate/modify those properties. After you try to determine the gradient and create a framer animation, if you continue have issues update your question with your new code. Either way, CSS `color` will not accomplish what you are trying, gradient or possibly other properties could.

Comment: At a very basic level. Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-text-gradient-nffeb?file=/src/styles.css) with radial-gradient, animating `backgroundSize`/`background-size`. You can also try linear-gradient instead of radial-gradient and play around with the stops, sizes, and positions.

Answer (score 0):

For future if you are looking for left to right text animation, I was able to achieve this with linear gradient and background-size as in Alexander example:

```
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 5%, #0B132A 5%, #0B132A 100%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
```

then animate with Motion

```
  <motion.div
    animate={{ backgroundSize: "10000px" }}
    transition={{ duration: 3 }}
  >
    Text to animate
  </motion.div>
```